# unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'function' and 'int'

Tags: python

```
def main():
    midterm=midtermgra
    final=finalgra
    semgra=semesterGrade(midterm,final)
    category(semgra)
def midtermgra():
    midterm=eval(input('Please enter your midterm grade: '))
    return midterm
def finalgra():
    final=eval(input('Please enter your final grade: '))
    return final
def semesterGrade(midterm,final):
    semgra=(midterm+(final*2))/3
    return semgra
def category(semgra):
    if(semgra<60):
        print('Semester grade: F ')
    elif(semgra<70):
        print('Semester grade: D ')
    elif(semgra<80):
        print('Semester grade: C ')
    elif(semgra<90):
        print('Semester grade: B ')
    else:
        print('Semester grade: A ')
main()
```

I'm trying to coding a structured program following teaching materials. However, it turns out to be a mistake

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'function' and 'int''.

I have reread my teaching slides, but can't figure out the problem.
Could anybody help me?

Comment: try `final=int(input('Please enter your final grade: '))` instead of `final=eval(input('Please enter your final grade: '))` you can also try `float` instead of `int` if u want

Comment: Still the same mistake :(

Comment: Did you mean: ‘midterm=midtermgra()’?

Answer (score 1):

YOu wrote midterm = midtermgra and midtermgra is a function so that is the reason

Comment: And then you are using midterm as an int in  semgra=(midterm+(final*2))/3

Answer (score 1):

You want to execute functions in `main()` in the two lines below, but left out the parentheses so that the interpreter knows you want to call these functions instead of assigning the function to a variable. When you later use `midtermgra` to calculate, the value is assigned to a function name, but the interpreter is expecting an `int`, thus the error message.

```
midterm=midtermgra
final=finalgra
```

should be

```
midterm=midtermgra()
final=finalgra()
```

Comment: I got it~What a silly mistake! Thanks for it